# CLEARTEXT communication not supported on Retrofit

Tags: android, http, ssl, retrofit

I'm trying to connect to https server on android using Retrofit. Here's my `OkHttpClient`

```
@Provides
public OkHttpClient provideContactClient(){
  HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
  ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
      .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
      .cipherSuites(CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,
          CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
          CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
      .build();
  interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
  SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = null;
  try {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, null, null);
    sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
  }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .addInterceptor(interceptor)
      .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
      .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
      .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
          if(responseCount(response) >= 5){
            return null;
          }
          String credential = Credentials.basic("user", "pass");
          return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
        }
      })
      .build();
}
```

However I keep getting `CLEARTEXT communication not supported:` exception

While debugging the `RealConnection` class I notice `route.address()` member does not have the `sslSocketFactory` despite it being assigned in Bulider.

Comment: You are making a request of an `http` URL, apparently, instead of an `https` one. Or, perhaps the `https` URL is redirecting to an `http` one.

Comment: Ok, now i get "Trust anchor for certification path not found" after changing to https.

Comment: Now, get rid of your `SSLSocketFactory`.

Comment: Same error pops up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

According to Network security configuration

> **The guidance in this section applies only to apps that target Android 8.1 (API level 27) or lower. Starting with Android 9 (API
>   level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.**

Create file res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">Your URL(ex: 127.0.0.1)</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

OR you can directly set in application in manifest like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: @Jitendra, Will this work even after the application is released on play store?

Comment: @sohali you need to add in app and release app again

Comment: hi @Jitendraramoliya i try it but not resolve problm, kindly suggest other way. thanks in advance

Comment: generally it's works and it's suggested by android it self. You need to check for other thing in such way

Comment: @AnilAtri Just add  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in application tag in androidmanifest.xml file

Comment: Fixed my problem, Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Adding only this to manifest (inside application)

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

works!

Comment: It works, but I fear this goes to production as well and might have some security implications

Comment: You an avoid that by using the "debug" source set. Create an AndroidManifest.xml file at `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` and apply it there. Manifest merging will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 9):

The CLEARTEXT message is due to requesting an `http` URL, either directly or via a server-side redirect (e.g., starts with `https`, then redirects to `http`).

In terms of your "trust anchor for certification path not found" message, your server appears to be using some SSL certificate that is not backed by one of the standard ones on whatever Android environment you are testing on. For example, perhaps your server is using an self-signed SSL certificate.

Options include:

- Using [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html) on Android 7.0+
- Using [my backport of network security configuration](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity) on Android 4.2+
- Setting up an `SSLContext` that knows about your self-signed certificate, then attaching that to OkHttp, such as is illustrated by [this OkHttp recipe](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java)

Comment: I did all this with a cert that was given to me for the site I try to access. Still the same error.

Comment: @hubert: Talk to the people who gave you the cert, then, and work it out with them.

Answer (score 0):

Also "CLEARTEXT communication not supported exception" may be easily produced even in old Android devices (6.0, 5.0, 5.1, etc.) by OkHttp library if you request an http:// host with a https/tls ConnectionSpec settings.

Answer (score 0):

[usesCleartextTraffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dybrb.png)

use tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic" in your manifest.xml file

Comment: This is used for having multiple manifest files.If your project contains more than one manifest file you can use the above code in AndroidManifest.xml file under application.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're encountering, "CLEARTEXT communication to 192.168.0.107 not permitted by network security policy," indicates that your Android app is attempting to communicate with a server (192.168.0.107) over an unencrypted connection (HTTP) rather than an encrypted connection (HTTPS). Android's network security policy, starting from Android 9 (Pie), enforces secure communication by default, and it doesn't allow unencrypted traffic.

To resolve this issue, you have a few options:

Use HTTPS: The most secure option is to configure your server to use HTTPS (SSL/TLS). This involves obtaining an SSL certificate for your server and configuring your web server software (e.g., Apache, Nginx) to use SSL. Once your server is set up with HTTPS, you can communicate with it securely from your Android app.

Network Security Configuration: If you need to communicate with an insecure server for development or testing purposes, you can create a network security configuration file that allows clear text traffic to specific domains or IP addresses. This should only be used for development, and it's not recommended for production use.

Create a network security configuration XML file (e.g., network_security_config.xml) in your Android project's res/xml directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Then, reference this configuration in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...
>
```

Be cautious with this approach, and never use it in a production environment.

Use an Emulator or Device with Lower Android Version: If you are running your app on a physical device or an emulator with Android 8.0 (Oreo) or lower, you won't face this issue because they don't enforce network security policies in the same way as newer Android versions. However, this is not a recommended long-term solution, as it does not address the underlying security concern.

For a production environment, you should always aim to use HTTPS (option 1). Insecure communication should be avoided wherever possible to protect data transmission and maintain security.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy